# Opening documents from OneDrive in Explorer triggers Office to ask for activation, why?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-office-2013

I've installed OneDrive for Business in order to access/sync my work files from my college's I.T system. As my college does not provide Microsoft Office for students (some do) I bought a copy of Office 2013 Professional (bought a couple of years ago).

File syncing is working beautifully, but however it seems that Office wants a separate licence for documents that are opened with OneDrive.

For instance, if I open a document outside of the OneDrive for Business directory (e.g, my Desktop), Office will say that it is activated, but however if I attempt to open a document inside the Windows Explorer OneDrive for Business directory, Office will ask to be activated (and close if I cancel).

---

Opening document from inside OneDrive for Business:

[image]

Opening document outside OneDrive for Business:

[image]

---

It seems like Office is *force-closing* without closing the document opened first (leading to the Document Recovery sidebar being opened on next launch), **but however I am able to open a OneDrive for Business document from within an Office application without being prompted for activation (Office sees itself as activated).**

My Office is fully licenced & activated; why does it ask to be activated when opening a OneDrive for Business document from Explorer (as mentioned above, this doesn't happen when opening said document from within an Office application)?

I've tried to (re)activate Office when prompted using my product key, but however I receive the following message:

> We're sorry, but Word has run into an error that is preventing it from
>   working correctly. Word will need to be closed as a result.

I've already tried reinstalling Office & OneDrive for Business, but it hasn't made a difference. Might this be some requirement that my college's server sets that my installation does not meet (such as only using their Office for Enterprise licence key)?

This is occurring on a copy of Office 2013 Professional x64 with OneDrive for Business x64 (compatibility requires that the two need to be the same architecture), on Windows 10 Professional x64.

*Note that I'm using OneDrive for Business as the regular SkyDrive application does not support ADFS authentication, which is what my college uses.*

Comment: I see from the office screenshot that you are not signed into a Microsoft account, but out of curiosity have you tried signing into the same Microsoft account on both products?  I'm just curious if that makes a difference, and if you can, check if the network you are connected to makes a difference (I.E. connect to McDonald's Wifi).

Comment: It seems like M$ thinks your account license is being used somewhere else.

Comment: @dakre18 Was thinking that, I tried it and I still recieved an error (however this time it was a 'this account doesn't have a licence for this product' error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more information on the versions you have installed and the installation
method would be useful, especially as regarding which installations are MSI
(desktop installations) and which are click-to-run.
As there are many reports about such incompatibilities,
I will assume below that you are running into the same problem.

An explanation for the problem can be found in the thread
[OneDrive for Business asking to Activate Office](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/409003),
where Tim Liu from MSFT Support said :

> The coexistence of an Office 2013 MSI (Office 2013 Professional Plus)
>   and Office 2013 Click-to-Run (OneDrive for Business from portal)
>   installation on the same computer is not supported. It may cause some
>   unexpected issues.
>
> If the issue happens again, we suggest that you only install Office
>   365 ProPlus which includes both Office applications and OneDrive for
>   Business.
>
> You can follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Remove Office 2013 Professional Plus with the Fix it tool in [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2013-Office-2016-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).
> 2. Sign in to the Office portal with your work/school account and click the setting gear on the right top. Choose Office 365 settings>Software>Office>Install.

Some [other answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3gx707/sidebyside_installations_of_msi_and_clicktorun/) is (I'm not too sure about this one) :

> Install the click to run first, then install the MSI. I have 75 users
>   on 365 and many have Visio/Project installed also that are from MSI.

If you have the opposite problem, having installed the Click To Run version
of Office and wish to switch to the MSI Edition, see the procedure
in the article
[MSI vs Click To Run Office installations – How to switch](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/msi-vs-click-to-run-office).

If this does not work for you, the thread
[OneDrive for Business asking to Activate Office](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/412502)
has these workarounds :

> First two potential workarounds (which seem to work for us):
>
> 1. Launch the Office application (e.g. Word, Excel,...) from the desktop and browse to the One Drive for Business folder to open the
>      document (from within the Office application File > Open)
>
> OR
>
> 2. Launch the Office application from the desktop and leave it running in the background. Then using the Windows file explorer, navigate to
>      the One Drive for Business location and double click the file like you
>      normally would

Comment: That hit the nail right on the head, I installed Office ProPlus 2013 with an MSI installer. Unfortunately an installer for Office365 isn't available/offered by the college at the moment, will have to request it.

Comment: Until then you could use one of the workarounds. I mentioned above the claim that installing C2R first and then MSI gives better results, but I don't really believe in it.

Answer (score -1):

Open One Drive Settings.  Select Office tab. Uncheck 'Use Office 2016 to sync Office files that I open.'  Now you will not be required to sign in every time you open a file from One Drive using File Explorer. It comes at a cost to collaboration so read the more info!